# Android Default Settings Option Activity Linking

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-settings

I'm developing a basic simple android application & want the default settings to lead to other activity,

I know this is kinda silly and out topic but I really don't understand how can I default action bar's setting option make lead to my other activity.

[image]

The bottom settings option pops up when clicked menu or in some phones on action bar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to create and start a new activity on the click event of the menu option. In your code, you will have something like this

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.my_menu, menu);
    return true;
}
```

The above code will inflate the menu XML file. Now, to take some action when an menu option is clicked, you use this code:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle item selection
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.settings:
        //start your activity here
        return true;
    default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```